# multiple insert queries in one webpage

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

i am trying to make this work. but nothing pops up after i click save.
there is a proper connection with the database, column names in database are also same as what i have given, rechecked.
newbie and needs help.
rectify my mistake please, i cannot find one:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submitted1'])==1) {

    $areas12   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['areas12']);
    $maxp12   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['maxp12']);
    $minp12   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['minp12']);
    $areae12   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['areae12']);
    $volume12   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['volume12']);

    $amount_change = $areas12-$areae12;
    $percent_change = ($amount_change/$areas12)*100; 

    $q = "INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['user_name']." (year, area_s, maxp, minp, area_e, volume,amount_change, percentage_change ) VALUES ('2012-12-31', '$areas12', '$maxp12', '$minp12', '$areae12', '$volume12', '$amount_change', '$percent_change')" ;
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    if ($r) {
        echo 'please fill up the data of year 2012-13';
    } 
    else {
        echo 'please enter some data or error :'.mysqli_error($dbc);
        echo '<p>'.$q.'</p>';
    }

}

if (isset($_POST['submitted2'])==1) {

    $areas13   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['areas13']);
    $maxp13  = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['maxp13']);
    $minp13   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['minp13']);
    $areae13   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['areae13']);
    $volume13   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['volume13']);

    $amount_change = $areas13-$areae13;
    $percent_change = ($amount_change/$areas13)*100; 

    $q = "INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['user_name']." (year, area_s, maxp, minp, area_e, volume,amount_change, percentage_change ) VALUES ('2013-12-31', '$areas13', '$maxp13', '$minp13', '$areae13', '$volume13', '$amount_change', '$percent_change')" ;
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    if ($r) {
        echo 'please fill up the data of year 2013-14';
    } 
    else {
        echo 'please enter some data or error :'.mysqli_error($dbc);
        echo '<p>'.$q.'</p>';
    }

}

if (isset($_POST['submitted3'])==1) {

    $areas14   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['areas14']);
    $maxp14   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['maxp14']);
    $minp14   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['minp14']);
    $areae14   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['areae14']);
    $volume14   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['volume14']); 

    $amount_change = $areas14-$areae14;
    $percent_change = ($amount_change/$areas14)*100; 

    $q = "INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['user_name']." (year, area_s, maxp, minp, area_e, volume,amount_change, percentage_change ) VALUES ('2013-12-31', '$areas14', '$maxp14', '$minp14', '$areae14', '$volume14', '$amount_change', '$percent_change')" ;
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    if ($r) {
        echo 'please fill up the data of year 2014-15';
    } 
    else {
        echo 'please enter some data or error :'.mysqli_error($dbc);
        echo '<p>'.$q.'</p>';
    }
}


if (isset($_POST['submitted4'])==1) {

    $areas15   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['areas15']);
    $maxp15   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['maxp15']);
    $minp15   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['minp15']);
    $areae15   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['areae15']);
    $volume15   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['volume15']);

    $amount_change = $areas15-$areae15;
    $percent_change = ($amount_change/$areas15)*100; 

    $q = "INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['user_name']." (year, area_s, maxp, minp, area_e, volume,amount_change, percentage_change ) VALUES ('2013-12-31', '$areas15', '$maxp15', '$minp15', '$areae15', '$volume15', '$amount_change', '$percent_change')" ;
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    if ($r) {
        echo 'please fill up the data of year 2015-16';
    } 
    else {
        echo 'please enter some data or error :'.mysqli_error($dbc);
        echo '<p>'.$q.'</p>';
    }
}


if (isset($_POST['submitted5'])==1) {

    $areas16   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['areas16']);
    $maxp16   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['maxp16']);
    $minp16   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['minp16']);
    $areae16   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['areae16']);
    $volume16   = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['volume16']);

    $amount_change = $areas16-$areae16;
    $percent_change = ($amount_change/$areas16)*100; 

    $q = "INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['user_name']." (year, area_s, maxp, minp, area_e, volume,amount_change, percentage_change ) VALUES ('2013-12-31', '$areas16', '$maxp16', '$minp16', '$areae16', '$volume16', '$amount_change', '$percent_change')" ;
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    if ($r) {
        header('location:stock.php');
    } 
    else {
        echo 'please enter some data or error :'.mysqli_error($dbc);
        echo '<p>'.$q.'</p>';
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<?php include('../config/css.php'); ?>
<?php include('../config/js.php'); ?>     
<title>stock details</title>
</head>
<body>


    <?php  include('../template/navigation.php'); ?>

    <h1><center><strong>Farm Stock Details</strong></center></h1>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <table class="table" align="center">
        <tr>
            <thead>
                <td>year</td>
                <td>Area at the starting year</td>
                <td>Maximum profit per hectare</td>
                <td>Minimum profit per hectare</td>
                <td>Area at the ending year</td>
                <td>Area in hectare</td>
                <td></td>
            </thead>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2011-2012</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="areas12" name="areas12"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="maxp12" name="maxp12"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="minp12" name="minp12"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="areae12" name="areae12"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="volume12" name="volume12"></td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block">Save</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted1" value="1">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2012-2013</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="areas13" name="areas13"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="maxp13" name="maxp13"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="minp13" name="minp13"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="areae13" name="areae13"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="volume13" name="volume13"></td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block">Save</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted2" value="1">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2013-2014</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="areas14" name="areas14"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="maxp14" name="maxp14"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="minp14" name="minp14"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="areae14" name="areae14"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="volume14" name="volume14"></td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block">Save</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted3" value="1">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2014-2015</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="areas15" name="areas15"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="maxp15" name="maxp15"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="minp15" name="minp15"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="areae15" name="areae15"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="volume15" name="volume15"></td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block">Save</button>
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted4" value="1">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2015-2016</td>
            <td><input type="number" id="areas16" name="areas16"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="maxp16" name="maxp16"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="minp16" name="minp16"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="areae16" name="areae16"></td>
            <td><input type="number" id="volume16" name="volume16"></td>
            <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block">Save</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted5" value="1">
            </div></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add a "Form" element in your html otherwise the submit button will not submit anyting.

Comment: thanks for the editing.

i am new for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bear in mind, a submit input without a parent form or a js listener won't do anything. So the simplest way will be to make a `<form>` that have as action your page name, for example:

```
<form action="<?echo $PAGE_NAME?>" method="POST" >
     <table class="table" align="center">
    <tr>
        <thead>
            <td>year</td>
            <td>Area at the starting year</td>
            <td>Maximum profit per hectare</td>
            <td>Minimum profit per hectare</td>
            <td>Area at the ending year</td>
            <td>Area in hectare</td>
            <td></td>
        </thead>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>2011-2012</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="areas12" name="areas12"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="maxp12" name="maxp12"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="minp12" name="minp12"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="areae12" name="areae12"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="volume12" name="volume12"></td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block">Save</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted1" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>2012-2013</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="areas13" name="areas13"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="maxp13" name="maxp13"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="minp13" name="minp13"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="areae13" name="areae13"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="volume13" name="volume13"></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block">Save</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted2" value="1">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>2013-2014</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="areas14" name="areas14"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="maxp14" name="maxp14"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="minp14" name="minp14"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="areae14" name="areae14"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="volume14" name="volume14"></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block">Save</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted3" value="1">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>2014-2015</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="areas15" name="areas15"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="maxp15" name="maxp15"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="minp15" name="minp15"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="areae15" name="areae15"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="volume15" name="volume15"></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block">Save</button>
            <input type="hidden" name="submitted4" value="1">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>2015-2016</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="areas16" name="areas16"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="maxp16" name="maxp16"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="minp16" name="minp16"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="areae16" name="areae16"></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="volume16" name="volume16"></td>
        <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn btn-block">Save</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted5" value="1">
        </div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```